# display microphone activity in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flash, microphone

I want to display a real time activity bar for the microphone in flex. This is similar to the vertical bar one can see when flash settings dialog's microphone settings tab is displayed.

Any built in component or link would help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since no one ever responded I will answer this as to how I eventually did it.
I used an image and the microphone's activityLevel attribute to show the the real time sound input to the microphone. Since this activityLevel is not bindable I had to use a timer.

Also do remember to get a valid value of activityLevel apart from  calling

microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();

also use

microphone.setLoopBack(true);

microphone.setUseEchoSuppression(true);

Otherwise the activityLevel value is -1 
The second point is not mentioned in flex docs

Answer (score 0):

yes, the point is, that you need to use the microphone.
either with microphone.setLoopBack(true); or netstream.attachAudio(microphone)